# h5py not built properly against mpi4py

Tags: python, build, h5py, mpi4py

I am trying to build h5py against mpi4py. My purpose is to be able to share a file among multiple processors. h5py is installed on the system but probably not with the link to mpi4py.
In fact, when I run the following example script:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import h5py

rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.rank  # The process ID (integer 0-3 for 4-process run)

f = h5py.File('parallel_test.hdf5', 'w', driver='mpio', comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD)

dset = f.create_dataset('test', (4,), dtype='i')
dset[rank] = rank

f.close()
```

I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h5py_example.py", line 6, in <module>
    f = h5py.File('parallel_test.hdf5', 'w', driver='mpio', comm=MPI.COMM_WORLD)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 259, in __init__
    fapl = make_fapl(driver, libver, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py", line 61, in make_fapl
    kwds.setdefault('info', mpi4py.MPI.Info())
NameError: global name 'mpi4py' is not defined
```

I have tried to build h5py as following:

```
python setup.py build --mpi --hdf5=/opt/local/
```

but this gives me the following problem:

```
error: option --mpi not recognized
```

I have also tried an installation with homebrew and pip
(hoping that mpi4py had been linked automatically)
without success.

How can I install parallel h5py properly?

Comment: I had the same problem, with packages installed from apt. This should be adressed also by the maintainers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `python setup.py configure --mpi --hdf5=/path_parallel_hdf5_lib/`
2. `python setup.py build`
3. `python setup.py install --prefix=/wheretoinstall_h5py`
4. `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/wheretoinstall_h5py`

You might also need to pre-install cython

Comment: This might be obvious (I don't know Python) but can you explain why the OP should be using 'configure' instead of 'build'?

Comment: could you report the steps of the installation since the beginning? I have downloaded the tar archive with hdf5.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you should [edit] that info you just commented to Helios83 into your answer.

Comment: @BSMP, ok sure, (my first time to post on stackoverflow)

Comment: #Jaylin what are good choices for wheretoinstall_h5py? I'm on mac

Comment: for the moment, after I follow the procedure and try to import h5py I have the following problem: ImportError: dlopen(/Users/me/Downloads/h5py-2.5.0/build/lib.macosx-10.10-x86_64-2.7/h5py/defs.so, 2): Symbol not found: _H5Fget_mpi_atomicity

Comment: Hi @Helios83, if you try on Mac, why not use Anaconda, http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/build.html, it's super easy to have everything included.

Comment: @Helios83, the error shows you need a parallel hdf5 library installed as shared library. This takes long to install on mac. for 'wheretoinstall_h5py', I don't have preference, you may create another director under Documents, say /Users/me/Documents/Projects/h5py-install. (I still recommend you to try the Anaconda, I used it on mac, the only reason that I want to install H5py seperately is because I want to modify its source codes, you know that the library is not perfect yet)

Comment: @Jaylin, it doesn't look like the anaconda builds are setup for MPI.